# How do I invoke my app using Square Point of Sale app's Other Payments feature?

Tags: ios, point-of-sale, square-connect

I have built an Alternate payment app that expects to work off "Other Payments" - takes the merchant to my app that lets them complete the transaction.

On the Square POS app, the "Other Payments" button seems to function like a "mark as paid".

Is there a way to use "Other Payments" to launch my app?

This is how I have made it function with other POS apps. Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot launch a different application from the payment flow of Square Point of Sale.